# Data Undefined After Send Data To Another Pages ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, api

Hello I have some problems regarding my project.
First in NewCases2.jsx, I did the POST API method to get app_uid, and the data appeared after I tried it on the console.

But when I send the app_uid data to the next page, the value changes to undefined.
For more details, you can check the script below :

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import './NewCases2.css'
import user2 from '../../images/user2.png';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Axios from 'axios';

class NewCases2 extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            token: sessionStorage.getItem("access_token"),
            username: sessionStorage.getItem("username"),
            user_role: '',
            search: '',
            app_uid: '',
            inMemoryCases: [],
            dataSess: [],
            allcases: [],
            dataApps: [],
            dataUser: [],
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if (window.sessionStorage.getItem("access_token") === null) {
            this.props.history.push('/');
        }
        Axios.get('https://bpm.**************.or.id/api/1.0/***************/extrarest/login-user',
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.state.token,
                }
            })
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(result.data);
                this.setState({
                    dataUser: result.data
                })
                this.getUserRole(this.state.dataUser.uid)
            })

        Axios.get('https://bpm.**************.or.id/api/1.0/**************/extrarest/session-id',
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.state.token,

                }
            })
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(result.data);
                this.setState({
                    dataSess: result.data
                })
            })

        Axios.get('https://bpm.**************.or.id/api/1.0/**************/case/start-cases',
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.state.token,
                }
            })
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(result.data);
                this.setState({
                    allcases: result.data,
                    inMemoryCases: result.data
                })
            })
    }

    onTask = (pro, tas) => {
        const apiUrl = 'https://bpm.**************.or.id/api/1.0/**************/cases'
        const dataApp = {
            'pro_uid': pro,
            'tas_uid': tas,
        }
        Axios.post(apiUrl, dataApp,
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.state.token,
                },

            }).then((result) => {
                console.log(result.data);
                this.setState({
                    dataApps: result.data
                });
            })
    }

    getUserRole = (uid) => {
        Axios.get(`https://bpm.**************.or.id/api/1.0/**************/user/${uid}`,
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.state.token,
                }
            })
            .then(result => result.json())
            .then(resultJSON => {
                if (resultJSON.usr_role == "PROCESSMAKER_ADMIN") {
                    this.setState({ user_role: 'Administrator' })
                } else if (resultJSON.usr_role == "PROCESSMAKER_OPERATOR") {
                    this.setState({ user_role: 'Operator' })
                } else if (resultJSON.usr_role == "PROCESSMAKER_MANAGER") {
                    this.setState({ user_role: 'Manager' })
                }
            })
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.dataApps.app_uid)
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <div className="background-nya">
                    <div className="header">
                        <Link style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }} to="/menu">
                            <p className="headerLabel-fix"> ************* </p>
                        </Link>
                        <p className="headerLabelUser"> {this.state.username} </p>
                        <p className="headerLabelPass"> {this.state.user_role} </p>
                        <img className="userIcon" src={user2} />
                    </div>
                    <p className="titlePage"> PROCESS LIST </p>
                    <div className="form-search">
                        <input type="text" value={this.state.search} onChange={this.searchData} placeholder="search"></input>
                    </div>
                    <Fragment>
                        <br />
                        {
                            this.state.allcases.map((process) => {
                                return (
                                    <Fragment>
                                        {/* This is when I deactivate the Link function to switch pages and the app_uid appears on 
                                        the console */}
                                        
                                        {/* <Link
                                            to={{
                                                pathname: "/dynaform",
                                                state: {
                                                    uid: this.state.dataApps.app_uid,
                                                    session: this.state.dataSess
                                                }
                                            }}
                                        > */}
                                        <div className="caseList" onClick={this.onTask.bind(this, process.pro_uid, process.tas_uid)}>
                                            {process.pro_title}
                                        </div>
                                        {/* </Link> */}
                                    </Fragment>
                                )
                            }
                            )


                        }
                    </Fragment>
                </div>
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
    
}


export default NewCases2;
```

From the script above (Without Link Function) the post data appears like this:

```
NewCases2.jsx: 92 {app_uid: "3205285525f34df467df8d0053057805", app_number: 325641}
NewCases2.jsx: 121 3205285525f34df467df8d0053057805
```

Then this is when I add the Link function to / dynaform at the same time I send the Session ID & UID data

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import './NewCases2.css'
import user2 from '../../images/user2.png';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Axios from 'axios';

class NewCases2 extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            token: sessionStorage.getItem("access_token"),
            username: sessionStorage.getItem("username"),
            user_role: '',
            search: '',
            app_uid: '',
            inMemoryCases: [],
            dataSess: [],
            allcases: [],
            dataApps: [],
            dataUser: [],
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if (window.sessionStorage.getItem("access_token") === null) {
            this.props.history.push('/');
        }
        Axios.get('https://bpm.**********.or.id/api/1.0/**********/extrarest/login-user',
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.state.token,
                }
            })
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(result.data);
                this.setState({
                    dataUser: result.data
                })
                this.getUserRole(this.state.dataUser.uid)
            })

        Axios.get('https://bpm.**********.or.id/api/1.0/**********/extrarest/session-id',
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.state.token,

                }
            })
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(result.data);
                this.setState({
                    dataSess: result.data
                })
            })

        Axios.get('https://bpm.**********.or.id/api/1.0/**********/case/start-cases',
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.state.token,
                }
            })
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(result.data);
                this.setState({
                    allcases: result.data,
                    inMemoryCases: result.data
                })
            })
    }

    onTask = (pro, tas) => {
        const apiUrl = 'https://bpm.**********.or.id/api/1.0/**********/cases'
        const dataApp = {
            'pro_uid': pro,
            'tas_uid': tas,
        }
        Axios.post(apiUrl, dataApp,
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.state.token,
                },

            }).then((result) => {
                console.log(result.data);
                this.setState({
                    dataApps: result.data
                });
            })
    }

    getUserRole = (uid) => {
        Axios.get(`https://bpm.**********.or.id/api/1.0/**********/user/${uid}`,
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.state.token,
                }
            })
            .then(result => result.json())
            .then(resultJSON => {
                if (resultJSON.usr_role == "PROCESSMAKER_ADMIN") {
                    this.setState({ user_role: 'Administrator' })
                } else if (resultJSON.usr_role == "PROCESSMAKER_OPERATOR") {
                    this.setState({ user_role: 'Operator' })
                } else if (resultJSON.usr_role == "PROCESSMAKER_MANAGER") {
                    this.setState({ user_role: 'Manager' })
                }
            })
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.dataApps.app_uid)
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <div className="background-nya">
                    <div className="header">
                        <Link style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }} to="/menu">
                            <p className="headerLabel-fix"> ************* </p>
                        </Link>
                        <p className="headerLabelUser"> {this.state.username} </p>
                        <p className="headerLabelPass"> {this.state.user_role} </p>
                        <img className="userIcon" src={user2} />
                    </div>
                    <p className="titlePage"> PROCESS LIST </p>
                    <div className="form-search">
                        <input type="text" value={this.state.search} onChange={this.searchData} placeholder="search"></input>
                    </div>
                    <Fragment>
                        <br />
                        {
                            this.state.allcases.map((process) => {
                                return (
                                    <Fragment>
                                        <Link
                                            to={{
                                                pathname: "/dynaform",
                                                state: {
                                                    uid: this.state.dataApps.app_uid,
                                                    session: this.state.dataSess
                                                }
                                            }}
                                        >
                                        <div className="caseList" onClick={this.onTask.bind(this, process.pro_uid, process.tas_uid)}>
                                            {process.pro_title}
                                        </div>
                                        </Link>
                                    </Fragment>
                                )
                            }
                            )


                        }
                    </Fragment>
                </div>
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
    
}


export default NewCases2;
```

Then the data sent earlier I console on the DNNewCases.jsx page like this

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Iframe from 'react-iframe'
import '../NewCases/NewCases.css'
import user2 from '../../images/user2.png';


class DNNewCases extends Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            username: sessionStorage.getItem("username"),
            token: sessionStorage.getItem("access_token"),
            session: this.props.location.state.session,
            uid: this.props.location.state.uid,

        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if (window.sessionStorage.getItem("access_token") === null) {
            this.props.history.push('/');
        }
    }



    render() {
        console.log("Props APP_UID : ", this.state.uid);
        console.log("Props Session ID : ", this.state.session);
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <div className="background-nya">
                    <div className="header">
                        <Link style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }} to="/menu">
                            <p className="headerLabel-fix"> ************* </p>
                        </Link>
                        <p className="headerLabelUser"> {this.state.username} </p>
                        <p className="headerLabelPass"> {this.state.user_role} </p>
                        <img className="userIcon" src={user2} />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <Iframe src={'https://bpm.*************.or.id/*************/en/neoclassic/cases/open?APP_UID=' + this.state.uid + '&DEL_INDEX=1&action=EDIT&sid=' + this.state.session}
                            width="100%"
                            height="100%"
                            display="block"
                            position="fixed" />

                    </div>

                </div>
            </Fragment>
        )

    }

}

export default DNNewCases;
```

From the script above, the data that appears on the console is only the session id while the uid is undefined.

```
DNNewCases.jsx: 31 Props APP_UID: undefined
DNNewCases.jsx: 32 Props Session ID: 3149643205f34e042776f23096193239
```

So, how do you make the value from app_uid in the DNNewCases.jsx console not undefined.

I hope to find a solution here.
Thank you ~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
`to={{
pathname: "/dynaform",
    state: {
        uid: this.state.dataApps.app_uid,
        session: this.state.dataSess
    }
}`


this.state = {
        token: sessionStorage.getItem("access_token"),
        username: sessionStorage.getItem("username"),
        user_role: '',
        search: '',
        app_uid: '',
        inMemoryCases: [],
        dataSess: [],
        allcases: [],
        dataApps: [], <---- this one
        dataUser: [],
    }
```

in your state is dataApps an array ([]), if I'm right can't you access something from an array as if it were a obj. In this case this.state.dataApss.app_uid.

i think you're supposed to set state to this.state.app_uid not dataApps.app_uid